# Insert multiple rows from a row using FOR LOOP

Tags: php, mysql

can i inserting into mutiple rows mySQL from one row php with FOR LOOP in MySQL?

i have a form like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="inputRecord" id="inputRecord">

<input type="text" name="member" id="member" value="Member A">
<input type="text" name="debit" id="debit" value="5000">
<input type="text" name="credit" id="credit" value="1000">

<input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="OK">

</form>
```

if i submitted to mySQL become like this:

```
id |  Member  |  Debit  |  Credit
---------------------------------
1  | Member A |   5000  |   1000
2  | Member A |   5000  |   1000
3  | Member A |   5000  |   1000
4  | Member A |   5000  |   1000
5  | Member A |   5000  |   1000
6  | Member A |   5000  |   1000
```

This is may code:

```
$var_i = 10;
if(isset($_POST['member'])) {
    $var_detailMember = $_POST['member'];
}
if(isset($_POST['debit'])) {
    $var_detailDebit = $_POST['debit'];
}
if(isset($_POST['credit'])) {
    $var_detailCredit = $_POST['credit'];
}
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    for($i=0;$i<=$var_i;$i++) {
        $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO transaction (member, debit, credit) VALUES ('$var_detailMember', '$var_detailDebit', '$var_detailCredit')";
        mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
        mysql_query($insertSQL, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Thank you for helping me

Comment: So you want to insert the same data 6 times? And what is your specific _problem_ with that? You know how a basic `for` loop works, right?

Comment: Where is your PHP code ?

Comment: yes you can, although I can't see why it would be useful. Just run the same INSERT statement 6 times using a loop. What have you tried?

Comment: Re your update: Your code is using the long-deprecated mysql_ code library. It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using mysqli or PDO as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Below code, Here 10 Records will be inserted

```
<form action="save.php" method="POST" name="inputRecord" id="inputRecord">
  <input type="text" name="member" id="member" value="Member A">
  <input type="text" name="debit" id="debit" value="5000">
  <input type="text" name="credit" id="credit" value="1000">
  <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="OK">
</form>

//save.php
<?php
$limit=10;
$Member=Escape($_POST['member']);
$Debit=Escape($_POST['debit']);
$Credit=Escape($_POST['credit']);
$Insert = "INSERT INTO table_name(Member,Debit,Credit) values('".$Member."','".$Debit."','".$Credit.")";
for($i=1;$i<=$limit;$i++){
  $Inserting=mysqli_query($dbconnection,$Insert);
}

function Escape($string){
$string = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', '', $string);
return $string;
}
?>
```

Comment: This code demonstrates the simple idea of using a loop to repeat the insert, but buyer beware: 1) It appears to be manually generating the ID, which can lead to duplicate IDs / key violations if more than one person tries to run the code at the same time (easily done in a web environment). Use an auto-increment key instead, don't insert it from the code.

Comment: 2) The code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: 3) This code is using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library. It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Downvoted for violating just about every principle of writing safe and correct SQL using PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You've corrected points 1 and 3, but not 2.

Comment: i've tried this code @Brindha Baskaran, but the browser appear like this `Fatal error: Call to undefined function Escape() in ... `

Comment: have you defined the function

Comment: oh yes, i'm sorry... @Brindha Baskaran i forgot it. Ok nice code.

Comment: Thank you very much @Brindha Baskaran. God bless you

Comment: Thank you to all participants for helping me, God bless you all

Comment: @BrindhaBaskaran this "Escape" function is not a substitute for proper parameterisation